# ViewPager crashes on orientation change - fragments stack up and cause OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-bitmap

My project structure looks like this:

MainActivity->PagerFragment->PagerViewAdapter which holds multiple PagerImageFragments

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryException after a couple of orientation changes but the pager displays bitmaps "efficiently" (I used AsyncTask/LruCache). Then I noticed that the memory used by app multiplies itself after each orientation change and from logs I can see that onCreate() in PagerFragment is called twice each time. I reckon that because of that my fragments get recreated and stack, causing the issue. How do I stop that from happening?

I tried setting

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
// super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Which did nothing for me. Then I tried:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Which made my PagerFragment recreate only once, but that's still not what I wanted.

**EDIT**: I changed MainActivity a little so it only does the initialization stuff if there is no saved instance and deletes all fragments when starting a new one. I deleted setRetainInstance(true). I can now change orientation numerous times (it will still end in OOM exception, but it takes much longer to trigger it). But now there is another problem - if I leave PagerFragment for another fragment and come back it crashes.

---

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG = "LOG";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
    ...
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        PagerFragment fragment = new PagerFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    ...
        switchContent(new PagerFragment());
    }
}

    public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = fm.getFragments();
    if (fragmentList != null) {
        for (Fragment frag : fragmentList ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "switchContent: destroying "+frag);
            fm.beginTransaction()
              .remove(frag).commit();
        }
    }

    fm.beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
      .commit();
}
```

Inside PagerFragment:

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerViewAdapter(getFragmentManager(), pdfFactory.getPageCount());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setPageMargin((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin));
    pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

PagerViewAdapter:

```
public class PagerViewAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final int size;

    public PagerViewAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
        super(fm);
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PagerImageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

}
```

PagerImageFragment:

```
public class PagerImageFragment extends Fragment {
private PhotoView photoView;
int position;
private MyCache<Integer, Bitmap> myCache;

public static PagerImageFragment newInstance(Integer pos) {
    final PagerImageFragment f = new PagerImageFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", pos);
    f.setArguments(args);

    Log.d("DISPLAY", "Bundling...");

    return f;
}

public PagerImageFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Initialize the cache
    myCache = new MyCache<>( 5 * 1024 * 1024 );

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate and locate the main ImageView
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_element, container, false);
    photoView = (PhotoView) v.findViewById(R.id.pager_image);
    Bitmap image = myCache.get(position);
    if (image != null) {
        photoView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
    else {
        new SetImageTask(photoView, myCache).execute(position);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Exception(after edit):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:770)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug in FragmentStateViewPager - it doesn't delete the views. The fix is to use this instead, although not perfect but best thing I could find https://github.com/adamsp/FragmentStatePagerIssueExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/fragmentstatepagerissueexample/app/FixedFragmentStatePagerAdapter.java

Answer (score 2):

add this in your activity in manifest

**android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"**

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
</activity>
```

**onConfigurationChanged** will be called when orientation changes but your activity will not be recreated but instead **onConfigurationChanged** will be called and you have to manage the orientation changes **if there are any**. So it can prevent **OutOfMemoryException** problem due to recreation of everything on orientation change.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Handle orientation changes here
}
```

Comment: I posted only part of my app. This activity changes fragments, and only this one has this problem. If I add configChanges won't I break the rest of the app? I heard it's not recommended and I'm looking for a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use getFragmentManager for your Pager Adapter. Instead of it, use getChildFragmentManager

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerViewAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), pdfFactory.getPageCount());
```

If it won't help, add Leak Canary library to build.gradle dependencies to detect memory leaks https://github.com/square/leakcanary